# Why are people so quick to downvote questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I ask ignorant questions, but I always try doing research beforehand and try my best to make my questions clear, concise, and grammatically correct.

Here's an example: [Fatal error: Call to private method ChildClass::foo() from context 'ParentClass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698127/fatal-error-call-to-private-method-childclassfoo-from-context-parentclass)

I did research on the error by searching on here and on Google, and read the PHP documentation page on inheritance, but still being confused and not finding an answer I asked my question on here.

My question is short, to the point, includes fully functional example code, and a link to a working IDE One example. I give the exact error, explain my (incorrect) reasoning, and ask what I am doing wrong. Despite this, it has already garnered two downvotes in only a few minutes.

Perhaps if I had spent more time reading about inheritance and method scoping I would have been able to answer my own question, but aside from my question being a little ignorant, it seems to me like an exemplary question.

Why are people are so quick to downvote questions on here? When I'm perusing the site, I'm constantly seeing what I think are good questions being downvoted. It's almost like people just enjoy downvoting as a pastime.

I think this mentality is backwards and not conducive to learning. It also seems far more prevalent on StackOverflow than any of the other StackExchange communities I am a part of. Instead of berating someone for asking a well-formed (although ignorant) question, they should be encouraged to learn.

Chances are, at some point someone will have the same question I did and find it on here through searching. So why downvote it if it contributes to this great repository of knowledge?

Comment: People are also pretty quick with upvotes, if the question or answer deserves it, so what?

Comment: _I always try doing research beforehand_ I don't see any any of that research in your question. I searched for "php private" and the first page I found was the [PHP manual on Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) which I think answers your question.

Comment: I'm with @SotiriosDelimanolis. In fact, I closevoted your question because it is a duplicate of the very first question shown in my "related questions" list.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was searching on the subject of inheritance and never landed on that page. If I had, I would have seen the answer to my question in the first paragraph. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Did you actually read the question you marked mine as a duplicate of, though? It has the same title and the same error, but the context is completely different. As I said in a comment to an answer to my question, I understood private parent methods could not be called from a child, but didn't realize that worked the other way around as well. The questions are totally different.

Comment: Essentially, becasue so many posters ask questions that can be plainly identified as bad from one glance, if not from the actual title itself.  For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707160/c-program-crash-while-trying-to-print-a-bidimensional-array.  I pegged that as 'almost certainly done no debugging' from the title.

Comment: Sigh.  It's a very simple error and the PHP tag is full of people making similar trivially answered questions. **Your question was *asked* very well.** It's just that the subject was poor.  And that PHP sucks in general, so the people trolling that tag are always in a bad mood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most significant criticism I have is that - while you've made some effort to provide a minimal example instead of dumping masses of code like many askers do - you still could certainly have made the code shorter. Here's an alternative version of your question's code that demonstrates the same issue more straightforwardly and in just over half as many lines, which took me about 30 seconds to create:

```php
<?php

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private function foo() {
        echo 'hello world!';
    }
}

class ParentClass {
    public function bar () {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass;
$obj->bar();
```

I don't think your question deserved downvotes, though. It was basic, but clear and answerable.

Comment: Very important point. A working example is a must in most cases, but you have to boil it down to the minimum. Otherwise the more knowledgeable see it, think "this guy is too lazy to put some work in it before asking", and downvote you in one second.